# Can anyone Identify this plugin from the syntax?

Tags: joomla-3.x

I'm helping out with a Joomla/Vm website that someone else has built and there are alot of custom modules which use syntax such as:

```
[module class="top-cart" type="mod" params="93" modstyle="none" /]
Cart
[module class="top-account" type="mod" params="103" modstyle="standard" /][clearfix /]
[clearfix /][googlefont font_family="Roboto Slab:300" size="18px" color="#333333" font_weight="300" align="none" margin="15px" class=""]100% Satisfaction Guaranteed[/googlefont][clearfix /]
Account
[module class="" type="mod" params="16" modstyle="standard" /]
```

I've never seen this before, and cannot seem to idenitfy the plugin which allows this to be used. Has anyone used this type of syntax in Joomla before?

Regards
Donna

Comment: Personally, I'd download the entire `plugins` directory to your computer, open up you're preferred Text Editor, and do a **mass find** for `modstyle`. Think this will give you your answer.

Comment: Did you find the above code in the database (i.e. contents of a page/article)? It resembles shortcode of WYSIWYG page builders. The `[clearfix /]` shortcode gives that away as it's not actually outputting data but CSS styles.

Answer (score 2):

Sorry you are not very clear with your description, however what I suspect is that you see this syntax inside an article or a custom html module, which likely is being used to load other Joomla modules. 
The syntax could be from any kind of plugin so it's not something that you could get a certain answer on it.

If it's important for you to find out the plugin then the place to look for is the plugin manager. You will have more luck if you search first at the content plugins and then the system ones.

I bet there should be not that a high number of plugins installed there that would make it impossible to identify the possible one. If in doubt, then you can find out by disabling temporary one by one, and refreshing the relative page that loads this content in the front-end, till you see the above code being displayed instead of the module's content.